# How to discover all branches and PRs in a same pipeline but only build the PRs automatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Context: jenkins declarative dsl for self hosted bitbucket

I need to implement a pipeline that can discover branches and PRs and trigger auto build for PRs only. I can not find such configuration on the jenkins document, so I need to use two pipeline like this:

Pipeline 1: discover both PRs and branches and disable auto build

```
// branches and PRs discovery
traits: [
    headRegexFilterWithPRFromOrigin: "features/.*",
],

// Supresse automatic build
// work around, match on empty string so jenkins does not trigger auto build on other branches and PRs
suppressAutomaticTriggerBranchRegex: '^$',
suppressAutomaticTriggerStrategy: 'NONE'
```

Pipeline 2: discover PR only and trigger auto build

```
// Discover branches/PRs by regex, and exclude branches
traits: [
    headRegexFilterWithPRFromOrigin: "features/.*",
    discoverBranches               : false,
],

suppressAutomaticTriggerBranchRegex: '.*',
suppressAutomaticTriggerStrategy: 'INDEXING'
```

Is there anyway to merge the two pipelines above into one?

Comment: Don't know if useful, but we work with GitHub and only build branches that look like `PR-\d*` which triggers builds on all PRs and none of the branches. When building PR, the `BRANCH_NAME` is `PR-...`. This is done in the GUI configuration of the multi-branch pipeline.